# What is the conceptual difference between User.first.followers.count and User.first.followers.to_a.count?

Tags: rails-activerecord, railstutorial.org, sqlite3-ruby

The two Active Record queries: `User.first.followers.count` and `User.first.followers.to_a.count` evaluate to the following SQL queries respectively:

```
[4] pry(main)> User.first.followers.count
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
   (0.3ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = ?  [["followed_id", 1]]
=> 4
[5] pry(main)> User.first.followers.to_a.count
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  User Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" INNER JOIN "relationships" ON "users"."id" = "relationships"."follower_id" WHERE "relationships"."followed_id" = ?  [["followed_id", 1]]
=> 4
```

How are they conceptually different?

This question came up in an exercise question at the end of section [14.1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/following_users#sec-exercises_followers) in [The Rails Tutorial](https://www.railstutorial.org/book)

He gives the following hint:

> Hint: Suppose that the user had a million followers.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Count(\*) vs Count(1)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221559/count-vs-count1)

Comment: I don't think you can call this a significant difference. We are talking about a single data-point with sub-millisecond response time. Note that the first query is identical in both cases, but takes 0.2ms vs 0.1ms in your two samples. You need to benchmark more extensively.

Comment: It's possible that you measured the cache effect. You need to do more repetitions, and use a timer with a better resolution.

Comment: Thank for the comments, I see that the time may be misleading. I know there is some sort of difference between those two commands because the author is saying there is. But I'm not sure what the conceptual difference is between the two so I'm not sure what to search for. I know In both cases we're getting the count of a collection of items but in the second instance it's an array. On the database level this has some sort of effect, b/c the sql commands are different, but I'm not sure what the difference is in words.

Comment: The first version counts in the database, the second version selects all rows and counts in Ruby.

Comment: @Thilo in the second version are all the rows pulled out of the database? In the first version do they stay?

Comment: `select count` will return just the number of rows. `select *` will return the rows (with all their columns) themselves.